# What is the best chess engine for 1 CPU?

Tags: engines

We have now GPUs, Quad-cores, i7s, i5s, i3s, and so on. However, I am wondering what is the best chess engine for 1 CPU. ChessBase offers Fritz 11 for free. Fritz 11 works very well with 1 CPU. Also, Stockfish has many versions, which one is the best for 1 CPU? Same question for Komodo. Komodo 12 is free, but what is the best Komodo for 1 CPU?

I tried Stockfish 14.1 and put my computer in trouble, even though is a new desktop, but with a Celeron processor. (Intel(R) Celeron(R) J4105 CPU @ 1.50GHz). It is impossible to analyze in my computer with Stockfish 14 because the computer freezes. I tried to use Stockfish 9 and Stockfish 10 but I did not find them in the Stockfish website. I only found Stockfish 14.

***Update 12/24***

I installed the last free version of Komodo (Komodo 12), and it is running without freezing my computer. I can analyze with this engine without problems. The same with Fritz 11. However, Stockfish 14 freezes my computer.

I am running the chess engines over the free GUI ChessBase Reader 17. You can find it in the following link:

https://en.chessbase.com/post/chessbase-reader-2017

You can download the free version of Komodo from the website: https://komodochess.com/

***Update 12/25/2021***

I found the old versions of Stockfish!

1. Go to https://stockfishchess.org/download/
2. Other Versions (At the end of the page)
3. Old (archived) releases of Stockfish

[image: Fritz 1 CPU]

Comment: Do you mean "best chess engine for 1 **core**?"

Comment: When you use ChessBase reader, they call it 1 CPU. However, you must be right. Most likely they use a more popular term.

Comment: GPU is short for Graphics Processing Unit, which doesn't affect any calculations that engines do (CPU is what matters). Quad-core means a CPU has 4 cores. i7, i5, i3 is Intel's naming scheme for their CPUs

Comment: For machine learning, it is better to use GPUs. So, I think that you are wrong. If I 
 am the one who is wrong, please correct me, after you research about GPUs and machine learning. However, my question is for computers that are not too powerful. I have noticed that in those computers, if you use Stockfish 14, almost all the resources of the computer are used by the chess engine.

Comment: What is most likely meant is best single process, single thread chess engine. Even with only a single core you can run multiple processes and or threads - I am not saying this is a good idea here, I am just being a pedant.

Comment: @justANewbie these days a major class of engines (Leela, Scorpio, Ara, etc) make use of GPU resources.

Comment: Stockfish 14.1 comes in two versions: one fast, but which requires a modern CPU (the AVX2 version), and one slower (the POPCNT version).  You are probably trying the AVX2 version on a CPU that doesn't support AVX2 instructions -- try the POPCNT version instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was using the one that is for less powerful processors. It calculates well but it is almost impossible to stop the analysis or play a move. I guess the solution would be to use the old versions of Stockfish like Stockfish 8 or 9. Currently, I am using the free version of Komodo, Komodo 12. Komodo 12 works well without any issue.

Comment: @letmewinpls45 in computer engineering reality, a core is a bona fide independent CPU; a so-called CPU is actually 4 CPUs packaged together in 1 chip for convenience, and called as 1 CPU for marketing purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stockfish is the unchallenged best CPU engine right now (it's most probably the best engine, period, as well). This applies regardless of the hardware you have, as long as it's a fair comparison - i.e. you run all your competing CPU engines on the same hardware.

Choose the [latest version](https://abrok.eu/stockfish/) of Stockfish, or if you prefer, choose the latest stable release ([v14.1](https://stockfishchess.org/download/)).

Comment: Hi! I tried Stockfish 14.1 and puts my computer in trouble, even though is a new one, but with a Celeron processor. (Intel(R) Celeron(R) J4105 CPU @ 1.50GHz). It is impossible to analyze with it because the computer freezes. I tried to use Stockfish 9 and Stockfish 10 but I did not find them in the Stockfish website. I only found Stockfish 14.

Comment: @Beginner for technical assistance I'd recommend asking a Stockfish developer - https://groups.google.com/g/fishcooking?pli=1

Comment: Thank you for your advice!

Comment: I found the old versions of Stockfish! This link is from the Stockfish website. I will try with them. Here is the link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/75gzfgu7qo94pvh/AAB3yfXx6PkUfHbBr4r_RwhGa

Comment: just set the number of cores. sf defaults to using all your cores, but you can tell it to only use 1

Comment: @OscarSmith I tried that but it did not work.

Comment: @OscarSmith In the sense that my computer froze anyway with the version 14 of Stockfish, using 1 CPU. What I mean by froze is that the analysis is showing the results, but it is almost impossible to switch to a different move.

Comment: @OscarSmith I am guessing that with the old versions of Stockfish, I would not have a problem. However, currently I am using the free version of Komodo that is called Komodo 12. Komodo 12 is working very well without freezing my computer.

Comment: @Beginner The computer freezes because you give too much hash to the engine. The hash is the [random access memory (RAM)](https://simple.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory) of your computer. If the computer runs out of RAM because you gave everything to the engine, then other tasks, like e.g. the rendering of the chess GUI, which also require RAM, can not function anymore. So, do not give more than a quarter or half of what you have to the engine. E.g. if you have 8 GB RAM, give 2048 or 4096 MB hash (multiples of 2) to the engine. Then your computer does not freeze.